# Submitting apps from multiple developer accounts

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

For historical reasons our company has ended up with two apps being developed with different Apple developer accounts. This isn't a problem right now (apart from having to enter all the UDIDs twice) but if we submit the apps to the iTunes store from different accounts will they show up as being developed by different companies? The company name in the app IDs is the same but I'm not sure if that's used.

Are there any other reasons why this would be a bad idea?

Comment: I see only one disadvantage — In "Other apps from this developer" section will be shown apps only for one account. You can transfer all apps to one account and close second (and save $80 per year).

Comment: 1 - the question is not about programming, and 2 -  it is "primarily opinion based". Both are against the SO guidelines,  as is the term "idiot" BTW.

Comment: I just get annoyed by downvotes with no comment to explain. There are plenty of other questions about iTunes Connect on SO and questions about development tools are allowed. It doesn't seem applicable to the "AskDifferent" site so I'm not sure where else it could . It's not opinion based - my main question was factual.

Comment: Upvoted - just for support of opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App B won't show up if you use the 'Developer apps' link of App A in iTunes, but this is a matter of taste.

You can always transfer the ownership of an app:
https://blog.sensortower.com/blog/2013/12/15/how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-ios-app-to-another-developer/